# Is it okay to pass (and subscribe to) an observable as a prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I sometimes like making use of local state in React. I also sometimes feel I'd like to trigger a function that modifies the child state.

Fortunately, it seems trivial to implement this by passing in a simple pubsub/observable/emitter object to the child via a prop, that the child subscribes to. I'm somewhat new to the React eco-system, so I'd like to know if this is acceptable or not.

For example, I'm creating a simple observable object like so:

```
const usePubSub = () => ({
  subscriber: null,
  emit() {
    if (this.subscriber) this.subscriber();
  },
  subscribe(callback) {
    this.subscriber = callback;
  }
});
```

And then hypothetically using it like this:

```
function Parent(props) {
  const pubsub = usePubSub();
  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => pubsub.emit()}>Click me!</button>
      <Child pubsub={pubsub} />
    </>
  )
}

function Child(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // !!!!! Danger?
  props.pubsub.subscribe(() => setCount(count + 1));

  return (
    <p>The count is: {count}</p>
  )
}
```

This would effectively allow me to alter the child's inner state with a button on the parent component, and in my testing, *seems* to work, however, I'm nervous since I can't find examples of anyone else doing something like this. Do you think that this is a good way ?

Answer (score 0):

So the "React way" of accomplishing what you're saying would be more like this:

```
function Parent(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me!</button>
      <Child count={count} />
    </>
  )
}

function Child(props) {
  return (
    <p>The count is: {props.count}</p>
  )
}
```

You don't need to subscribe to an observable in the child component because the child is already watching the props that are passed into it.

Comment: I agree that that's the more _correct_ way to do things, however, I was really hoping to create a `<Modal>` component that could contain its own `isVisible` state, and be remotely triggered to display via a button on its parent or sibling.

Comment: @CormanBros It's hard to know what the right way of structuring that would be without knowing more about what you're trying to do. If you wanted to control state from a child component though you could pass down a function as a prop like `setVisible={setVisible}`